# Video upload in rails 4 using delayed job is not uploading fully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I am uploading video(ex:2mins running video) in my rails 4 application.

It is uploaded successfully.

I need it to be run in background.

So I am using delayed jobs.

But after running in delayed jobs, I can see only 10secs of that video.

It was not fully uploaded.

Can any 1 help me?

Comment: what do you mean saying "run in background"?

Comment: upload using delayed job

Comment: So, i don't think you will manage to do this. DJ is running in background. And it has no connection with your browser.

Comment: As @PavelS said, you lose your connection to the browser.  You could however upload the file async from the browser possibly to allow the user to continue doing other things, but if they navigate away it could potentially be interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The upload happens in the client-server layer, so you can't hand off to Delayed Job to process it until that completes.

My guess is that you are firing off a job at the beginning of the upload process and it is being picked up by the background runner, therefore truncating the file before the upload completes